# simple way to read file input into struct array in c?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and I'm having a hard time understanding how to pass data into the struct array and print it. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct info
{
    int num1;
    char *name;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int num4;
} info;

info *create_array(int num_group)
{
    info *data = calloc(num_group, sizeof(info));

    return data;
}

int main(void)
{
    FILE *ifp;
    info *data;

    int num_group;
    int i;

    ifp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    fscanf(ifp, "%d", &num_group);
    printf("%d", num_group);

    data = create_array(num_group);

    for (i = 0; i < num_group; i++)
    {
        fscanf(ifp, "%d %s %d %d %d", &data->num1, &data->name, &data->num2, &data->num3, &data->num4);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < num_group; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %s %d %d %d", data->num1, data->name, data->num2, data->num3, data->num4);
    }
}
```

Sample Input: I want it to print exactly the same. The first number determine how many groups I have

```
4
4 string1 2 3 4
3 string2 5 8 9
1 string3 6 8 5
65 string4 65 87 55
```

Bonus: if you can guide me how to sort from lowest to highest using the first column, that would be awesome.

Comment: `fscanf(ifp, "%d %s %d %d %d", &data->num1,  ...)`

Comment: "I'm having a hard time understanding how to pass data into the struct array and print it." and `fscanf(ifp, "%d %s %d %d %d", data->num1, data->name, data>num2, data->3, data->num4...`  --> enable all compiler warnings to rapid feedback.

Comment: `info.name` has no memory allocated. At first, it will be easier if this `struct` member were `char name[42]` and extend the example later.

Comment: The only robust way to store a char* string to file is to first store the number of characters then followed by each character. If you don't care about file readability, consider binary storage, e.g. fread/fwrite(&data->num1, sizeof(int), 1, file);

Comment: The last line seem to have too many numbers

Comment: Original posted code does not compile, several errors; `data` never moves within either   loop, args to `fscanf()` need updates.  For sorting, see [qsort manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)

Comment: Sorry for the typos, I was trying to manually typing the code on stackoverflow. I copied the code from the IDE and all errors are fixed and I also added the & like wildplasser suggested but I'm not getting the desired output still.

Comment: Please always use copy/paste to present code, otherwise you will introduce problems that were not there.

Comment: @WeatherVane Aye sir, will do so from now on. Also I tried your suggestion of changing char *name to char name[42] but now only the last line get print 4 times.